# In the JavaScript, Why is the different output coming for Two same properties function?

Tags: javascript, object

** I have created two functions with different name & same properties and when I was checking surprisingly it's giving me different output. I don't understand what was is the problem exactly. I was expecting same result for both functions. See the below code**

```
function foo1()
{
  return {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}

function foo2()
{
  return
  {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}

console.log("foo1 returns:");
console.log(foo1());
console.log("foo2 returns:");
console.log(foo2());
```

Below is the Output:

```
foo1 returns:
Object {bar: "hello"}
foo2 returns:
undefined
```

Comment: `;` is automatically inserted after `return` in the second example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have a new line after your return statement in the second function.

So instead of returning the object with bar, it just returns without a specified value, which returns undefined.

Comment: What if we enclose the return value between parentheses? Good way or bad?

Comment: it still needs to be on the same line as the keyword return

Comment: Thanks! it means need be below way always!

function foo2()
{
  return
  {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}